# script working in Visual studio but not when running from Batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, networking, path

I have a script which supposed to run powershell with different credentials and then in that session supposed to goto network path and install a file:

```
$path1 = "\\192.168.10.10\bucket\test.exe"
Start-Process powershell -Credential $creds -ArgumentList "-Command &{Start-Process $path1 -Verb RunAs}"
```

looks like no problem running this from the ISE but when i save the ps file and tried to call it from batch file i get the folowing error:
[image]

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: `powershell.exe` or `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`. How are you calling `Start-Process` from batch? `powershell -command`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process) with the `-Credential` parameter, whatever happens to be the caller's *current directory* matters:

If the *target user* identified by the `-Credential` argument happens not have the required *permissions* to access the *caller*'s current directory, you'll get the error you saw.

The solution:

- Use the `-WorkingDirectory` parameter to specify a current (working) directory for the new process that the target user *is* allowed access to.
- Alternatively, switch to such a directory in the *caller*'s context first.

Comment: I tried something else but still getting error. the file i want to run is locallay now under: c:\programdata\mbsetup.exe     - i have checked and the user creds stored in the $creds have permission to run from there, if i log with the user i can go there and run the program but if i try do it from powershell i still get an error, any advice?

Comment: If `-WorkingDirectory c:\programdata` doesn't help, then I have no explanation. If you have a simple reproducible case, please ask a new question.